# Create_autonomy stops reacting

Tags: ros, roomba, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using create_autonomy with my Virtual machine .
I have ROS hydro installed with create autonomy.
But after running it for severel minutes on my roomba 780 I won't be able to send any more cmd_vel messages.
Basically the roomba will just continue to move in the last given direction.
Is there a simple solution to this problem or could it be caused by the virtual machine for instance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246067/create_autonomy-stops-reacting/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, the robot base will latch the latest command received, regardless of the status of the serial connection. For example, if the cable is disconnected mid-operation or the driver is not shutdown properly the robot will continue to execute the latest velocity command. I would double check that the cable you are using is not loose.  It could very well be a virtual machine related issue, but I cannot say for sure.

- See [USB issue with VM](http://answers.ros.org/question/212848/are-there-any-limitations-to-using-ros-in-virtualbox-ubuntu/?answer=212851#post-id-212851)

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-10-26**:
So good news it works perfectly fine when using raspberry so again it has something to do with virtual machine being unable to use USB ports properly.